# Get value of specific tag before the loop in XML

Tags: xml, oracle, report, bi-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I am working on one requirement where I need the value of **D_COMP_CODE** before the loop I am opening for **G_COMP_CODE**, so that I can apply logo in report based on the value of **D_COMP_CODE**.

Is it possible in XML/BI publisher?

Below is the sample code:

```
-<FAS420>
<P_BOOK>TEST</P_BOOK>
-<LIST_G_PARAMS>
    -<G_PARAMS>
        -<LIST_G_SETUP>
            -<G_SETUP>
                -<LIST_G_COMP_CODE>
                    -<G_COMP_CODE>
                        <D_COMP_CODE>01</D_COMP_CODE>
                    -</G_COMP_CODE>
                -</LIST_G_COMP_CODE>
            -</G_SETUP>
        -</LIST_G_SETUP>
    -</G_PARAMS>
-</LIST_G_PARAMS>
</FAS420>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a value from deep in the XML. Just put the full path and element name in the if statement. It will pull the value from the first record.